# oEmbed not recognising Vimeo URLs

Tags: oembed

I am trying to embed a Vimeo video into a post. I am inserting the URL into the page like so.

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.

http//vimeo.com/1234

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
```

It is outputted as the plain text URL. I have tried it with a youtube link and it worked perfectly. I have also tried wrapping it in the `[embed]` shortcode but that just wrapped it in anchor tags.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking into WordPress Core vimeo is registered like so:

```
'#http://(www\.)?vimeo\.com/.*#i' => array( 'http://www.vimeo.com/api/oembed.{format}', true  ),
```

But looking at vimeo API for oEmbed they show their URL without the `www.` so what you need to do is register vimeo oEmbed correctly:

```
add_action( 'init', 'add_vimeo_oembed_correctly' );
function add_vimeo_oembed_correctly()
{
    wp_oembed_add_provider(
        '#http://(www\.)?vimeo\.com/.*#i',
        'http://vimeo.com/api/oembed.{format}',
        true
    );
}
```

You can place this in your theme functions file or place in a plugin.

You may need to revisit posts that have Vimeo embeds and save again after putting this fix in.

Comment: Thank you. I inserted it into my init hook and it worked perfectly. I did not have any previous embed links so I do not know if you have to click update on all of your posts. I would imagine it is a filter on echo, not on save.

Comment: WP 3.3 Beta 1 works without the `www.` now.